# ImportError: cannot import name 'Document'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I ran a code generated in python 3.6.5, it perfectly worked (countless times), now I turned on my computer, runned it again (didn't change anything at all) and:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Document'
```

I tried to uninstall `docx` or `python-docx` via pip command according to previous posts, and:

```
Cannot uninstall requirement docx, not installed
```

then I tried to install, and:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/docx/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719) - skipping
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement docx (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for docx
```

What is going on here?

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
```

the third line gives the problem (apparently) and I'm working on a mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6

Full Error Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cezi/Desktop/Products_Field+Entries.py", line 5, in <module>
    from docx import Document
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docx/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from docx.api import Document  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docx/api.py", line 14, in <module>
    from docx.package import Package
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docx/package.py", line 9, in <module>
    from docx.opc.package import OpcPackage
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docx/opc/package.py", line 9, in <module>
    from docx.opc.part import PartFactory
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docx/opc/part.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ..oxml import parse_xml
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docx/oxml/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .section import (  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docx/oxml/section.py", line 7, in <module>
    from copy import deepcopy
  File "/Users/cezi/Desktop/copy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from docx import Document
ImportError: cannot import name 'Document'
```

Comment: Were you running this in anaconda or virtualenv? Also, can we see your code?

Comment: in terminal; I can't copy the code cause it contains some delicate info (use it for business purposes) but it's certainly not the code, I applied it, it worked, I closed it, turned the laptop off, turned it on later, doubleclicked the code, ran it, boom. It just seems like the module has been removed from my machine, without me doin anything.

Comment: Just the basics of the script, you can remove/exclude sensitive info, we only need to see what you are running to reproduce the problem. For example, if it's the `import`, then all we need is `import <some-package>` or whatever you are running there

Comment: Also, any extra info regarding how you call your script (bat/bash? command line?) and your platform (windows/mac/unix/linux) can also help pin down the issue

Comment: aight one sec, will post it above

Comment: Which version of `python-docx` are you using and with what platform?

Comment: In High Sierra using python 3.6.3, python-docx version 0.8.10, I can't replicate your issue

Comment: yeh me neither I hadn't had any problems with the script so far; absolutely no clue what's goin on. I could try to un- and reinstall python? I'll post the complete error code above if it helps you; the version of python docx is 0.8.9, by platform what do you mean? and my python version is 3.6.4

Comment: per [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5236) you may need to upgrade `pip` using `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3` if you can't use `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: damn dude I figured it out, an unknown PC was controlling my laptop; when I detected it it immediately disconnected and now it's working... watch out folks... Thanks a lot and sorry for wasting your time C.Nivs

Comment: I think I'm more curious now, did that only solve the `pip install` errors or the import? The import doesn't make sense off the bat... but whatever works I guess

Comment: haha I promise all I did was relaunching the script after cutting the connection to whoever that was; I didn't even close the script but just relaunched the one which failed by the import (which was still open) and boom all good, no more import errors nothing no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a PyPi package named `docx` which is *not* `python-docx`. The main module of the `docx` package is also named "docx", but it has no `Document` object. You need to get rid of the mistakenly installed one and add the right one. In `pip` you would remedy that this way:

```
$ pip uninstall docx
$ pip install python-docx
```

Comment: Nope I precisely tried that too according to one of your previous propositions I found scanny but obtained the exact same results. I swear all I did was cutting off an unknown machine which seemed to be connected to my laptop now it works. No clue what the heck that was. Apologies again for bothering, but who would expect that.

Comment: I've followed all the suggestions here and still getting the error message. I'm using Spyder - at one point I could "from docx import Document" from the Anaconda prompt but not from Spyder. Now I cannot even do it in the prompt window!